# How can I redesign octave

Tags: octave

I downloaded octave and accidentally pressed some buttons which changed the design of the software to be more specific it doesn't look like how my professor at university was working with it . Could you please help me to fix it in order to look like how it did in the beginning?
I upload a picture of how it looks like now

[image: octave software]

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall?

Comment: What OS are you using? This is relevant to help you locate the settings file.

Comment: 1) Have you tried asking your professor? 2) Please use SuperUser site for non-programming related questions

Answer (score 0):

OK, it appears you are only looking at the Editor window, which is normally docked with other windows like the command window, documentation, etc.  It also appears to be maximized, hiding everything else.

In the upper right you see two icons, one that looms like an x, and one that looks like two overlapping squares (two windows).  If you click the x, that should close the editor and you should be able to see the rest of your desktop including the rest of the octave GUI.  If you cannot see octave anywhere, of you are in Windows try using ALT-Tab or clicking on Octave in the task bar to make the window visible.

In the main octave window there should be  a "Reset Default Window Layout" menu item under the Window menu.  That should restore everything to the default layout without having to go to the trouble of a full reinstall.

The following YouTube video doesn't exactly match your problem, but it does show how to change and restore the GUI layout:
https://youtu.be/0USOvYHLqSU